# Spring boot: external properties file an PropertySource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, boot

I am developing a spring boot application with gradle.

I would love to tell spring where to read `.properties` files with a parameter. Since I am still running it via gradle, I have added this to my `build.gradle`

```
bootRun {
    args = [
            "--spring.config.additional-location=file:/path/to/my/props/folder/,file:/path/to/another/props/folder/"
    ]
}
```

into `/path/to/my/props/folder/` I have created a file `remote-connection.properties`:

```
### remote-connection
remote.ip.address=127.0.0.1
remote.ip.port=5001
```

and I am trying to load those props like this

```
@RestController
@PropertySource("file:remote-connection.properties")
public class MyController {

    @Value("${remote.ip.address}")
    private String remoteIpAddress;
}
```

When i run `./gradlew bootRun` i have the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [my.package.MyApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: remote-connection.properties (No such file or directory)
```

(I have also tried `@PropertySource("classpath:remote-connection.properties")` and `@PropertySource("remote-connection.properties")`)

It works flawlessly if I place `remote-connection.properties` into `src/main/resources`, but I want that config file to be outside the resulting jar, being able to run it with

```
java -jar my-application.jar --spring.config.additional-location=file:/path/to/my/props/folder/,file:/path/to/another/props/folder/
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Following this guide https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/ I have changed my run args to

```
bootRun {
    args = [
            "--my.props.folder=/path/to/my/props/folder",
            "--my.other.props.folder=/path/to/another/props/folder",
    ]
}
```

and loading props like this

```
@RestController
@PropertySource("file:${my.props.folder}/remote-connection.properties")
@PropertySource("file:${my.other.props.folder}/some-more.properties")
public class MyController {

    @Value("${remote.ip.address}")
    private String remoteIpAddress;
}
```

This way, it works!!